# Timer1 on low priority doesn't work

Tags: embedded, interrupt, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am using MPLAB XC8 compiler with [PIC18F87J11](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39778b.pdf) and I need to use the internal time1 for counting purposes. I noticed that my code works perfectly fine if the interrupt is set to high priority. However with low priority it doesn't work and I just can't figure it out.

**Timer 1 Settings:**

```
       // 1/1 prescalar
       T1CONbits.T1CKPS1 = 1;
       T1CONbits.T1CKPS0 = 1;

       // Use Internal Clock
       T1CONbits.TMR1CS = 0;

       // Timer1 overflow interrupt
       PIE1bits.TMR1IE = 1;

       // Enable Timer 1
       T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;

       INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // Enable Perpherial Interrupt
       INTCONbits.GIE = 1; // Enable Global Interrupt
```

**This works fine**

```
void interrupt high_priority lowISR(void) {
    if (PIR1bits.TMR1IF == 1) {

         Printf("\r\n 1 second");

        PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;
    }
    }
```

**However this doesn't and I don't know why.**

```
void interrupt low_priority lowISR(void) {
    if (PIR1bits.TMR1IF == 1) {

         Printf("\r\n 1 second");

        PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;
    }


}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually setting timer 1 to use the low-priority interrupt, and are you enabling interrupt priority control (by default, IIRC, all interrupts use high priority regardless of the individual-interrupt-source priority bit).

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the following, adding them fixed my issue. I found them [here](http://motor.feld.cvut.cz/www/materialy/A1M14RPO/T15a.c).

```
IPR1bits.TMR1IP = 0;            // Timer 1 -> Low priority interrupt group
PIE1bits.TMR1IE = 1;            // Enable Timer1 interrupt

RCONbits.IPEN = 1;              // Enable interrupt system priority feature
INTCONbits.GIEH = 1;            // Enable high priority interrupts
INTCONbits.GIEL = 1;            // Enable low priority interrupts
```